# While copying an image from an application, only the URI is copied onto the clipboard

Tags: android

```
    imageview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                //  android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                //   clipboard.setText(CopyText);
                //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied to Clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.chandigarh);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                        b, "Title", null);
                Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(path);
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(imageUri);
                ClipData data = new ClipData("label", new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, item);
              //  ClipData theClip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "Image", imageUri);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(data);
                Log.e("copy", String.valueOf(data));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "copy to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            //your stuff
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I am trying to copy an image on long tap. Above is my code but my problem is, when I paste only `uri` is showing. The image is not copied. Please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: `String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                        b, "Title", null);` Please tell which value for `path` you get.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        `. You could as well remove those two lines as you are doing nothing with the result in `bytes`.

Comment: Where you can paste your image, you can load your image with URI.

Comment: I want to paste this image into another application like wtsapp and facebook in message. is it possible to copy image from one application and paste into another application?